# How to understand the type of the convergence in probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

In this slide http://www.math.toronto.edu/mnica/Billingsley.pdf, I am learning the definition of convergence in probability. For function $f: R \to R$, we define $Pf=\int fdP=E(f)\in R$. We say a sequence of probability measures $P_n$ converges weakly to $P$ if every bounded and continuous functions $f$,
$$
P_n f= \int f dP_n \to Pf.
$$

I want to ask what type of this convergence $P_n f= \int f dP_n \to Pf$ (in what metric we used)?

For example, if we consider the empirical measure of a matrix
$$
P_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{\sigma_i}
$$
convergences to semi-circle law $P$.

But how to understand this convergence
$$
P_nf=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(\sigma_i)\to \int fd P
$$
So what sense of this convergence?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing two types of concepts of convergence. On the one hand, there is the weak convergence. Which is just really convergence of the laws of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ to a limiting law of a random variable $X$. Formally:

For random vectors $\left\{X_1, X_2, \ldots\right\} \subset \mathbf{R}^k$ we say that this sequence converges in distribution to a random $k$-vector $X$ if
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(X_n \in A\right)=\mathbb{P}(X \in A)
$$
for every $A \subset \mathbf{R}^k$ which is a continuity set of $X$. This definition can be shown to be equivalent (Portmanteau Lemma) to the one you presented: we say that a sequence of random elements $\left\{X_n\right\}$ converges weakly to $X$ (denoted as $X_n \Rightarrow X$ ) if
$$
\mathbb{E} h\left(X_n\right) = \int h dP_n \rightarrow \int h dP = \mathbb{E} h(X)
$$
for all continuous bounded functions $h $. And this type of convergence can be shown to be equivalent to convergence wrt to the Lévy–Prokhorov metric if the space where the random variables take values is separable.

On the other hand you have a different (and stronger!) concept of convergence in probability. A sequence $\left\{X_n\right\}$ of random variables converges in probability towards the random variable $X$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_n-X\right|>\varepsilon\right)=0
$$

This is literally what is happening for the Law of Large Numbers that you cited implicitly above. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). But the Law of Large numbers gives the stronger convergence in probability (which, by the way, implies the weak convergence or convergence in distribution, which is the first one I explained. The two concepts are equivalent when the sequence of random variables converges to a constant).

Comment: The weak law gives you convergence in probability to a constant. This is equivalent to convergence in distribution, not stronger.

Comment: Weak convergence is equivalent to convergence in probability only if the sequence of random variables converges to a constant. I wrote convergence in probability is a **stronger** concept than convergence in law, which indeed is. I did not write **strictly stronger**, I see no problem here.

Comment: Well, I want to ask what is the type of convergence in $\int f dP_n\to \int f dP$? Is this one convergence pointwise? I mean that is for every $\epsilon>0$, $|\int f dP_n-\int fdP|\le \epsilon$?

Comment: The type of convergence $\int f dP_n \rightarrow \int f dP$ for all bounded and continuous functions $f$ is the weak convergence (also called convergence in distribution). It's the first one I described, I also wrote there wrt to which metric (Levy-Prokhorov) the convergence happens in the space of probability measures.

Comment: @Hermi $\int f \, dP_n$ is a real number. So there is only one meaningful thing for the convergence to mean, i.e. convergence of a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: @AndrewZhang So that is the same meaning of the convergence of the sequence $a_n\to a$?

Comment: @Hermi It is not the same. The convergence you asked about happens **for all continuous bounded functions**! It is not a single $f$. The weak convergence talks about the convergence on the space of probability measures. It is not a simple convergence of a sequence of numbers. This is very misleading.